# Installing Perl GD on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: perl, gd, perl-module

My aim is to run Circos plot  on Ubuntu 14.04. I installed every perl modules required except GD and GD::Polyline. When I run the command **$sudo cpan GD**, it fails to install GD. I found similar problems reported [Here](http://www.cpantesters.org/cpan/report/4e32ae28-b495-11e4-8502-0b9cc5dea601) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27597167/cannot-install-gd-module-on-darwin-13-0-1-using-cpan). But I couldn’t understand and solve it. Can anyone know an alternative way to install it?

**Here is the error,**

```
 Reading '/home/junglab/.cpan/Metadata'
 Database was generated on Fri, 10 Apr 2015 05:41:02 GMT
 Running install for module 'GD'
 Running make for L/LD/LDS/GD-2.56.tar.gz
 Checksum for /home/junglab/.cpan/sources/authors/id/L/LD/LDS/GD-2.56.tar.gz ok

 CPAN.pm: Building L/LD/LDS/GD-2.56.tar.gz

 Configuring for libgd version 2.1.1-dev@.
Checking for stray libgd header files...none found.

Unknown option: installdirs
Usage: perl Build.PL [options]

Configure GD module.

 Options:
 -options       "JPEG,FT,PNG,GIF,XPM,ANIMGIF"   feature options, separated by commas
 -lib_gd_path   path            path to libgd
 -lib_ft_path   path            path to Freetype library
 -lib_png_path  path            path to libpng
 -lib_jpeg_path path            path to libjpeg
 -lib_xpm_path  path            path to libxpm
 -lib_zlib_path path            path to libpng
 -ignore_missing_gd             Ignore missing or old libgd installations and try to compile anyway

If no options are passed on the command line.  The program will
attempt to autoconfigure itself with the gdlib-config program (present
in GD versions 2.0.27 or later).  Otherwise it will prompt for these
values interactively.

Warning: No success on command[/usr/bin/perl Build.PL --installdirs site]
 'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
  LDS/GD-2.56.tar.gz

/usr/bin/perl Build.PL --installdirs site -- NOT OK
Running Build test
Make had some problems, won't test
Running Build install
Make had some problems, won't install
Could not read metadata file. Falling back to other methods to determine prerequisites
```

Comment: You can get some idea from these links: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21444787/4248931,
http://stackoverflow.com/q/17442932/4248931,
http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=868016

Comment: Why not just `apt-get install libgd-perl`?  Unless you need something newer than the packaged versions, I would never use CPAN.

Comment: I installed libgd as you suggested. But I got the same error when execute sudo cpan GD @SeanBright

Comment: "No package libgd-perl available."